# What would cause a "Method error 12152" in a cascading dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Bit of a long shot but has anyone come across a “Method error 12152” in a cascading dropdown list from the AJAX control toolkit? This is occurring in a system which is used globally but the error is only surfacing in Chinese language clients. There have been no recent codebase or server changes and the error has only just started and is occurring on multiple clients (again, only Chinese clients).

This doesn’t appear to be a server generated error as ASP.NET health monitoring is not picking up any events. A quick Google search only returns a handful of results and they’re predominantly in Chinese so my best guess is that this is a client generated error message possible related to an HTTP timeout but I'd really like a definitive answer on the error code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should rule out server errors.  This is a symptom of a web service method call failing.  I would double check the method in the debugger if you can.

Comment: I'm quite confident it isn't occurring on the server. All exceptions are logged and this one doesn't appear anywhere. I also can't find any references to error type 12152 all of which leads me to believe it's isolated to an idiosyncrasies with Chinese clients.

Comment: I imagine you're right about the clients, but every time I've ever had "method error ###" show up in a dropdownlist, it was because of a problem with the web service method.

Comment: Agree, it's very bizarre and I can't see why a client would throw that error but here we are! All other language clients continue to function as normal so I keep coming back to the Chinese language issue.